# How to read in IRAF multispec spectra?

Tags: python, spectrum, astropy

I have a spectrum in a fits file that I generated with Iraf. The wavelength axis is encoded in the header as:

```
WAT0_001= 'system=multispec'
WAT1_001= 'wtype=multispec label=Wavelength units=angstroms'
WAT2_001= 'wtype=multispec spec1 = "1 1 2 1. 2.1919422441886 4200 0. 452.53 471'
WAT3_001= 'wtype=linear'
WAT2_002= '.60 1. 0. 3 3 1. 4200.00000000001 1313.88904209266 1365.65012876239 '
WAT2_003= '1422.67911152069 1479.0560707956 1535.24082980747 1584.94609332243'
```

Is there an easy way to load this into python?

Comment: Do you have Pyfits or astropy installed?

Comment: @Tom. We discussed this on a Facebook group for astronomers and found the answer ourself. We wanted to open a post and give the answer for future references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been using [this](https://github.com/kgullikson88/General/blob/master/readmultispec.py) code, which was given to me by Rick White. However, the [specutils](http://specutils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specutils/read_fits.html) package is probably the better way to do it:

```
from specutils.io import read_fits
spectra_list = read_fits.read_fits_spectrum1d('mymultispec.fits')
print spectra_list[0]
   Spectrum1D([ 338.06109619,  395.59234619,  326.0012207 , ...,
         660.0098877 ,  686.54498291,  689.58374023])

print spectra_list[1].dispersion
   <Quantity [ 8293.44875263, 8293.40459999, 8293.36044556,...,
        8166.53073537, 8166.48250242, 8166.43426803] Angstrom>
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer? This way, a newcomer will know that this works.

Comment: I agree, specutils is the way to go.

Comment: specutils has now stopped supporting the multispec format as they restructured their code and haven't so far rewritten the multispec part. They may add it back in the future.

Comment: I would like to point out that specutils has been updated and the method explained here is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up on the answer from @kgully - and the related discussion: [specutils](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/) supports reading multispec files again (has for several years, even though it wasn't working for a bit in between these answers). The relevant code snippet (for *any* IRAF-formatted file) is now:

```
>>> from specutils import Spectrum1D
>>> spec = Spectrum1D.read('mymultispec.fits')
>>> print(spec)
Spectrum1D (length=762078)
flux:             [ 0.4408 adu, ..., -1.0 adu ],  mean=0.74146 adu
spectral axis:    [ 3726.7 Angstrom, ..., 9300.0 Angstrom ],  
mean=6094.4 Angstrom
```

and you replace `Spectrum1D` with `SpectrumCollection` if your multispec file actually has multiple spectra.